# MS Access: Trying to select a value in a record corresponding to a certain value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Sorry if the title is confusing.  But I have a table with a few different columns.  One column is the `KitNumber` and the other is the `ReturnDate`.  I am trying to select the value of the `ReturnDate` to see what the length of the entry is (also, does VBA let you get the length of a date?).  What I need to do though, is the user will enter a number in an unbound, and then that value will look in the table to see if it matches another value in there, and if it does, it will select the return date.  Here is the code I have now:

```
strSQL = "SELECT ReturnDate FROM Crew WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.AssignKit
Debug.Print strSQL
DateLen = Len(strSQL)
```

So say I enter '111111' in the unbound.  I want it to look in the table then to see if there is a matching number.  Then if there is it should return the `ReturnDate` value and get the length of it.  Cause right now the `Debug` just returns the `KitNumber` instead of the date.  Anyone be able to help me out?  Thank you

Comment: I have a couple of questions
1) is KitNumber a number or text data type?
2) are you aware that you are not actually executing the sql statement above, just preparing it?
3) can you explain a little more about the requirement to measure the length of the date. What is it that you are trying to tell exactly?

Comment: `Debug.Print strSQL` will only print out the whole select statement, not the result becuase as @ChrisProsser said you are not executing anything.  Try changing the last quote to this: ` = '" & Me.AssignKit & "'"` then you will have to set your strSQL to a recordset to extract the data.

Comment: `KitNumber` is a number. All I want to do with this is extract the `ReturnDate` value where the unbound value matches the `KitNumber`

Comment: @TKEyi60 How would I add a record set to this statement where I want to find the length of `ReturnDate` then?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one off, then a `DLookup` in the **OnExit** or **OnChange** events should give you the info you need to work with

using your example,

```
Debug.Print DLookup("ReturnDate","Crew","KitNumber = " & Me.AssignKit)
```

if KitNumber is stored as a string in the database, then you would need to put quotes around the selection

```
Debug.Print DLookup("ReturnDate","Crew","KitNumber = '" & Me.AssignKit & "'")
```

Note that DLookup returns the first one it finds, so if you need multiple values, you will have to look into recordset functions `.Find` and `.FindNext`